# TEIID Importing ddl into vdb ddl

Tags: teiid

Currently my VDB DDL file is getting quite big. I want to split into different files using the following.

IMPORT FROM REPOSITORY "DDL-FILE"
INTO test OPTIONS ("ddl-file" '/path/to/schema1.ddl')

However, this does not seem to work.

- Can the DDL file path be relative, how?
- The schema test, can it be VIRTUAL?
- Does "DDL-FILE" refer to "ddl-file"?
- What should I put in my main VDB ddl and what should I put in my extra ddl's. Should the
  extra ddl's contain server configuration details or should they be defined as a VDB.

I would like to see a working example on how to use this.

This will be used in a teiid springboot project where you can only load one main vdb file. It is not workable to have one very large ddl file.

I tried multiple approaches but it does not seem to work, either giving me a null pointer with no error codes or error codes that tell me nothing.

Also the syntax in Teiid 9.3 seems different:

IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA public
FROM REPOSITORY DDL-FILE
INTO test OPTIONS ("ddl-file" '/path/to/schema.ddl')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is currently not implemented in Teiid Spring Boot. This issue is captured in https://issues.redhat.com/browse/TEIIDSB-219

Update: I added the needed code to master, should be available with 1.7 release meanwhile you can build the master branch and test it out.

Comment: Thanks for adding it! We will look into it.